# What kind of object is a Reactive Java Subscription?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

In Reactive Java, we're told that the `.subscribe()` call returns "a Subscription reference". But `Subscription` is an *interface*, not a class. So what kind of object are we handed that implements this interface? Do we have any control over this?

There is the class `Subscriptions` that can create and return several different kinds of `Subscription`, but what does one do with them? If I write

```
Subscription mSub = Subscriptions.create(<some Action0>); 
mSub = someObservable.subscribe();
```

won't my just-created `Subscription` simply be overwritten by whatever the `.subscribe()` call returns? How do you use a `Subscription` you create?

(On a somewhat related note, what is the point of `Subscriptions.unsubscribed()`, which "returns a Subscription to which unsubscribe does nothing, as it is already unsubscribed. Huh?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You shouldn't care.

Longer answer: a subscription gives you two methods:

- `unsubscribe()`, which causes the subscription to terminate.
- `isUnsubscribed()`, which checks whether that has already happened.

You can use these methods to a) check whether an Observable chain terminated and b) to cause it to terminate prematurely, for example if the user switched to a different Activity.

That's it. You aren't exposed to the internals *on purpose*. Also, do you notice that there's no `resubscribe` method? That's because if you want to restart the operation, you need to resubscribe to the Observable, giving you a new Subscription.

Answer (score 1):

As you know `Subscription`s are used to keep references to ongoing `Observable`s, mainly for resources' management. For example in Android applications, when you change an `Activity` (screen) you flush old `Activity` `Observable`s. In this scenario, `Subscription` instances are given by `.subscribe()` (as you mentioned) and stored. So, for which reason would one create a `Subscription` directly, especially `Subscriptions.unsubscribed()`? I encountered two cases:

- Default implementation; avoid declaration like `Subscription mSub;` that would be filled latter and could create an NPE. It's especially true if you use Kotlin that require property initialization.
- Testing

Comment: Thank you. Questions: does storing an Android Activity Subscription somehow allow reconnecting to the Observable when the Activity is restarted? Can you give an example? How would I use a created Subscription in a default implementation? I have declared some Subscriptions (for RxAndroidBle) in an Android app and it doesn't seem to cause a problem.

Comment: The main usage of keeping `Subscription` reference is to call later `.dispose()` on it. So if you don't handle unsubscription just drop the `Subscription` reference, write `myObservable.subscribe();` without assigning it to a variable. A typical usage is to subscribe in `onResume()` method, storing the `Subscription`, and in `onPause()` to call `subscription.dispose();`

Answer (score 0):

> On a somewhat related note, what is the point of Subscriptions.unsubscribed(), which "returns a Subscription to which unsubscribe does nothing, as it is already unsubscribed. Huh?

In 1.x, `Subscriptions.unsubscribed()` is used to return a `Subscription` instance the operation was completed (or never run in the first place) when the control is returned to your code from RxJava. Since being unsubscribed is stateless and a constant state, the returned `Subscription` is a singleton because just by looking at the interface `Subscription` there is no (reasonable) way to distinguish one completed/unsubscribed `Subscription` from another.

In 2.x, there is a public and internal version of its equivalent interface, `Disposable`. The internal version is employed mostly to swap out a live `Disposable` with a terminated one, avoiding `NullPointerException` and null checks in general and to help the GC somewhat.

> what does one do with them?

Usually you don't need to worry about `Subscriptions.create()`; it is provided for the case you have a resource you'd like to attach to the lifecycle of your end-subscriber:

```
FileReader file = new FileReader ("file.txt");

readLines(file)
.map(line -> line.length())
.reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b)
.subscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>() {
     {
         add(Subscriptions.create(() -> {
             Closeables.closeSilently(file); // utility from Guava
         });
     }
     @Override public void onNext(Integer) {
         // process
     }
     // onError(), onCompleted()
});
```

This example, demonstrating one way of usage, can be expressed via `using` instead nonetheless:

```
Observable.using(
    () -> new FileReader("file.txt"), // + try { } catch { }
    file -> readLines(file).map(...).reduce(...),
    file -> Closeables.closeSilently(file)
)
.subscribe(...)
```